# How do you disable your Rasp Pi Adblocker?

Tags: video, streaming-video

I know. Nobody likes advertisements, but I need the Raspberry Pi's adblocker disabled; Whilst being completely oblivious to the knowledge that there was an adblocker in the Rasp Pi's system!

So yes, just tried to run an internet program, which the Raspberry Pi deems an "ad", while sidebar and header ads are still showing, which get me confused:

Why can't I run a video because of the adblocker but sidebar and header ads bypass an adblocker I don't even know about?

If you didn't understand, the main question here is "How do you disable the Rasp Pi adblocker?

Comment: IIRC you can either right click it or use the extensions menu in your browser.

Comment: You might want to (need to) add the OS and particular software you are using.